# How to sort out the structure based on the result and show the output according to ranking?

Tags: c++, arrays, output

I have just started learning C++ programming a month or so ago. I am having a great difficulty in ranking and printing out the output based on the ranking. I followed some of the ideas posted in the forum and my code is below.  I have no idea of what I have missed and how the code works.  What I am trying to do is to sort out the `player_data[5]` in ascending order based on the attempt field and then sort out again the `player_data[5]` with time elapsed where the order of the array is based on the attempt and then time elapsed if the attempt is the same.  After I sort out the structure of array, I want to `cout` based on the ranking.  Would someone tell me what I am missing and give a brief explanation on the code itself. TIA

```
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
bool player_sorter(player_score const& lhs,player_score const& rhs);

struct player_score
{
    char name[31];
    int num_attempt;
    time_t time_elapsed;
} player_data[5];

bool player_sorter(player_score const& lhs, player_score const& rhs)
{
    if (lhs.num_attempt != rhs.num_attempt)
        return lhs.num_attempt < rhs.num_attempt;
    if (lhs.time_elapsed != rhs.time_elapsed)
        return lhs.time_elapsed < rhs.time_elapsed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `std::sort` functions works with standard containers, as far as I know it doesn't with C-style array. You should define your type:

```
typedef struct player_score
{
    char name[31];
    int num_attempt;
    time_t time_elapsed;
} player_score;
```

And then declare the actual container of your data:

```
std::vector<player_score> player_data;
```

Once your filled your container you can sort it with

```
std::sort(player_data.begin(), player_data.end(), player_sorter);
```

The function sort is an implementation of a sorting algorithm, maybe a Quicksort. If you call it like this you are telling the function that you want to sort from the beginning to the end, the whole container. The third argument is the function that performs the `<` comparison and it is fundamental to determine if an element goes before or after the other.

Also, `player_sorter` must return a value even if the two `player_score` are equal, you should add a `return false` to the end of the function, because in that case the first operand is not strictly less than the second but it is equal. In the case the operator were `<=` you would return true.

Answer (score 0):

`std::sort` provides "good enough" sorting speed and complexity for most cases. Here is an example using a different struct and `std::sort` and several ways to sort.

```
struct foo {
    int a;
    int *b = nullptr;
    bool operator<(const foo & other) const {
        return (a < other.a);
    }
}
void printvec(const std::vector<foo> & vec) {
    for ( foo & f : vec ) {
        std::cout << f.a << "\t" << (void*)f.b;
        if ( f.b ) {
            std::cout << "\t" << *f.b;
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
bool sort_foos_on_b(const foo & a, const foo & b) {
    // if both are nullptr
    if ( (nullptr == a.b) && (nullptr == b.b) ) {
        return false;
    }
    // if one is nullptr
    if ( (nullptr == a.b) != (nullptr == b.b) ) {
        return (nullptr != a.b);
    }
    return (*a.b) < (*b.b);
}
void bar() {
    const constexpr size_t MAX_FOO = 20;
    std::default_random_engine generator;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> rng(0,MAX_FOO-1);
    std::vector<foo> vec(MAX_FOO);

    // initialize
    for ( foo & f : vec ) {
        f.a = rng(generator);
        if ( f.a & 1 ) {
            f.b = &f.a;
        }
    }

    // uses foo::operator<()
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    printvec(vec);

    // uses lambda
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const foo & a, const foo & b) -> bool {
        // sorting on pointer because why not
        return (f.a < f.b);
    });
    printvec(vec);

    // uses explicit sort function
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), sort_foos_on_b);
    printvec(vec);
}
```

`bool foo::operator<() const` is used to sort on `foo::a`.
The lambda is used to sort based on the pointer value of `foo::b`.
The explicit sort function is used to sort based on the nullness of `foo::b` and, if both are non-null, then the value pointed to by `foo::b`.

You can see tradeoffs for each. Using `operator<` will provide a default method of sorting (not needing to specify a sorting function to `std::sort`). The lambda allows you to customize your sorting right where you're using it. The explicit sorting function would be used if you need to sort the same way from different locations (instead of repeating the same lambda everywhere).

*disclaimer: I wrote above code snippet from memory and don't have access to a compiler at the very moment so it might not compile "as-is"*